# Call [tableView realoadData] on RootViewController from AppDelegate?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview

In my app I am making an HTTP request and waiting and updating my RootViewController with the data. The problem is, I need to make a call to [tableView reloadData] after my data collection has finished, as it stands right now the tableview will either be partially populated or not populated at all. I came across this thread:

[Passing an NSDictionary to a ViewController from AppDelegate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1648991/passing-an-nsdictionary-to-a-viewcontroller-from-appdelegate)

Which included this solution for setting data in the view conroller from app delegate, but I am wondering how I can adapt this for my situation? All I need, I think, is a reference to the rootViewController in appDelegate so I can call reloadData when I need to

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil tableDataSource:(NSArray*)tableData {
if (self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil]) {
    // Custom initialization
    tableDataArray = [tableData retain];

}
return self;
}
```

Thanks for any ideas

Comment: I ended up just moving the HTTP requests to the viewControllers to resolve the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare that `tableView` as a property such as `myTableView` in that class. Now reference that class and call `[classObject.myTableView reloadData];`

It should work.

Comment: This sounds like a good plan, I must be doing something wrong however. Added this to RootViewController.h: @property (nonatomic, retain) UITableView *tableView; and Xcode does not recignize the reference when I try [RootViewController.tableView reloadData]

Comment: I have made the change. Create an object for RootViewController and then use `object.tableView reloadData`

Comment: Thats part of the problem I'm having, I'm not sure how to get the instance of RootViewController. I tried this, Xcode can see the tableView reference here but I get a runtime error: (Thread 1: program recieved signal "SIGBRT")     RootViewController *rootViewController = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    [rootViewController.tableView reloadData];

Comment: @Hoofamon: you should get the property from an instance of RootViewController, not from the class.

Answer (score 1):

You can give the appDelegate a property that receives a pointer to the RootViewController and which is set by the RootViewController when it is initialized.

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil 
               bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil 
      tableDataSource:(NSArray*)tableData 
{
    if (self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil]) 
    {
        // Custom initialization
        tableDataArray = [tableData retain];
        (MyAppDelegate *)([[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]).rootController = self; 
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: I tried this code but Xcode did not like this line:   (MyAppDelegate *)([[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]).rootController = self; What I am not sure about is the .rootController as Xcode could not see the reference

Comment: You apparently implement the appDelegate in a class of your own. Let's assume the name of that class is `MyDelegate`. Give that class a `@property(nonatomic, assign) rootController;`, `@synthesize` it and you should be able to cast the result of `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]` to `(MyDelegate *)`. Now you can assign to its property. You may have to remove the () around the message.